# how to put condition users on tableau

Tags: tableau-api

im mysql user, i have data source like this

```
User_id     | Order_id    | Status_id | createdAt  | Transaction_Amount
```

user_id as the user, order_id as the id of the order, status_id as the status of each order, createdAt as the date of the transaction .

in MySQL, i divide the condition of the users in 4 conditions.

conditions 1 new_user

```
the user who doing FIRST transaction in date range, and not doing transaction before the date range
```

conditions 2 repeat_user

```
the user who doing transaction before the end of date range, and doing atleast 1 more transactions in date range
```

conditions 3 existing_user

```
the user who doing his first transaction before the date range, and doing atleast 1 more transactions in date range
```

conditions 4 unique_user

```
the user who doing transaction in date range
```

i've done it with the queries in mysql, but i want to visualize it in tableau, i already make the filter of the time range, but how to make the conditions to based on condition user

Comment: Can you please elaborate which kind of view/output do you want to create?  Or do you want to create these conditions itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to have create these conditions in tableau, I propose a solution like this.  Since you've not provided any data to work upon, a data I used in excel is as

[image]

**View-1** add a Calculated field(CF) `First Transaction of User` as

```
{FIXED [user_id]: MIN([CreatedAt])}
```

Drag this field on filter instead of created at and you'll get a view based on your `condition_1`.  Screenshot

[image]

**View-2** (I am assuming that both transactions may have been completed within the filtered date range.  If you need otherwise please specify).

- step-1. drag user_id to rows, createdAt at filters (select range of dates).
- Step-2 Drag order_id to filters again select count distinct, select at least `2`

You'll get a view like this

[image]

**View-3** Add two CFs as.  1st `condition 1` as

```
Min([First Transaction of User])< min([CreatedAt])
```

another CF `condition 3 check2` as

```
{Fixed [user_id]: COUNTD([order_id])}>1
```

Add both these CFs on filter shelf along with createdAt.  Add `condition-1 check2` to context (**important step**) select TRUE from both filters and you'll get desired view.  like this

[image]

**View-4** It is the most basic chart in tableau. Try and I am sure you can do it.  Good luck

Comment: thankyou for the explanation, i've forgot to put some explanation in here, so if the status_id = 7, then its not approved transaction. and i just want to visualize approved transaction (status_id != 7). 

ok next are, the condition i want to make are for the filters, so if the filters are for condition 1, then the users which match in condition 1 are appear, and the transaction in date range will visualize

Comment: so the condition are for the filter, if i choose the condition 1, then the users including the transaction are visualize (but only in date range), otherwise, its not.

Comment: In case if you want to further filter your view based on some other dimension, use it in filter accordingly and don't forget to add it to context(right clicking it).

Comment: example : for date range that you choose (05-01-2020 until 18-01-2020) and if i want to filtered with user condition 1 (new_user), then user_id who match are (5, 6, 7, 8) so it'll visualize all of the data in date range with selected users based on condition 1 terms, if i choose filter with user condition 2 (repeat_user), then user_Id who match are (1,2,4), so the data which visualize are the data for user_id 1,2,4 in date range

Comment: can i sent the csv to your email because i just have a tableau public account. here's the tableau tableau link https://public.tableau.com/views/asdasdasd_16045734152540/Sheet1?:language=en&:display_count=y&:origin=viz_share_link, thankyou anil

Comment: I have received the file.  Now please tell me what do you want?  Can you edit your question, please, in order to avoid extended chats here

Comment: like i mentioned before : example : for date range that you choose (05-01-2020 until 18-01-2020) and if i want to filtered with user condition 1 (new_user), then user_id who match are (5, 6, 7, 8) so it'll visualize all of the data in date range with selected users based on condition 1 terms, if i choose filter with user condition 2 (repeat_user), then user_Id who match are (1,2,4), so the data which visualize are the data for user_id 1,2,4 in date range

Comment: Proceed like second answer you may be able to get it.

Answer (score 1):

From your workbook it is clear that you want cohort analysis.  In this regard Let me explain a few things..

First create a `user cohort` like this

```
{FIXED [user_id]: MIN([CreatedAt])}
```

Output of this field will be date when user first ordered.  So if you will add this field to filters the output will be users (added in view) who first ordered within the filtered date/range.

Now if you want to see the users' orders during the same period (condition 1) also add the createdAt field to filters with same date/range.
E.g. suppose your date range is 5jan to 15 jan.  Then set both filters to these dates range.  First filter will ensure to filter customer with their first transaction and second one will give you desired output.

For condition2, you'll have to add countd(order_ids) to filters with filter value set 'at least 2'.
E.g.  setting this filter will ensure that customer did their first and at least one more transaction during the date range.

For condition3, changing dates in filter accordingly will do.  Nothing extra to be done.
E.g.  suppose you want the customers with second and onward transaction between 5 jan to 15 jan.  Then you will have to set first cohort filter with date upto 4 jan but second date filter to 5 jan to 15 jan

Condition 4: remove cohort from filters.  Set date range on createdAt field only.

If you want to add another filters like status etc., These will work after you add them to filters.

Try this

Comment: thankyou very much, and how to visualize in on the dashboard? is it make one sheet for each conditions so i make 4 sheet, then if i choose conditions 1, then dashboard will visualize sheet 1 and so on. is it correct?

Comment: Yes.  The views can be as per taste.  Most of your conditions are mutually exclusive so depicting on one viz may result in empty sheet.

Comment: but i think for the condition 2 and 3 you are wrong, because on condition 2, if the users are doing transaction before the range, and doing transaction again in range (for just once), then it's not appear, instead, what i want its appear, because the definition of "Repeat_users" is doing transaction before the last range, and doing transaction again at least 1 on the range, so the date before range are counted.

Comment: thankyou very much anil, anyway, i already marked this as an answer

Comment: great, this is what i want anil, so basically this is just edited the filter right? le't say i want to take range date between '2020-01-01' until '2020-01-03', and then when i filter condition 2, its user_id 19, and 20 for that conditions, but the conditions is just to find out the user_Id, after i found the user_id, i count let's say the transaction for user_id 19 and 20, but i just count the transaction in that range for user_id 19 and 20. is it just make the new filter based on the dates?